# explicit "this" binding : how does the .bind method work?

Tags: javascript

So I've been trying to learn a bit about JS context and understanding the "this" keyword. This is some code I've been working with:

```
var addNumbers = function(num1, num2){
  console.log(num1+num2);
}

var newAdd = addNumbers.bind(this,1,2);

newAdd();
```

The above logs the value 3, as it should. But if I call addNumbers.bind without the "this" keyword:

```
var newAdd = addNumbers.bind(1,2);
```

The newAdd() call returns NaN. Why does this NaN happen? and also, I only came across the solution of adding "this" as a first parameter by trying things out and not necessarily out of intuition. Why does passing "this" as a parameter work? and what context does the "this" in this case represent? Thanks.

**EDIT:** This question is different from any .bind() related questions because It is not asking for a general explanation of this function. I am asking about a specific use case and need a specific answer. Other suggested duplicates were more generalized and were more open to different types of answers.

Comment: @EngineerDollery added an explanation as to why it is not. The answer i'm seeking is more specific and it's about a certain aspect of .bind(), as opposed to a general explanation of .bind()

Comment: I'm not willing to remove my close-dupe vote on that basis, sorry. I think the referenced Q answers this query too -- and quite clearly. I think it's a duplicate of more than that question too, but I can only vote for one duplicate. The answers you have all tell you that the first argument is substituted for `this`, that's the same thing you'll learn by reading the linked dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.bind` is used to assign the "this" context to another object

In your case, `.bind(1,2)` assigned "this" as `1` and the parameters are `num1=2`, `num2=undefined`, and 2+undefined is NaN in JS

If you have a function in an object, say `obj.func(asd)`, `this`will be `obj` in the function func. If you want to change the context of `this`you can use `bind` or `apply` (that's like bind, but it calls directly the function, instead of creating a new one)

Comment: Wow that was it! Thank you for your answer. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, because the [`Function#bind` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) always takes the function's `this` context as the first argument:

> fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])

In your example, you are passing `1` as the value of `this` (which is not invalid, but is probably not what you're trying to do):

```
var newAdd = addNumbers.bind(1,2);
```

So if you don't need the `this` argument, you could just pass `null`:

```
var newAdd = addNumbers.bind(null, 1, 2);
```